# SQL select rows with constant column value per ID

Tags: sql

Given a dataset that looks like this.

```
ID_no |    Color
---------------- 
1     |    Blue 
1     |    Blue 
2     |    Green
2     |    Blue
3     |    Red  
4     |    Red
4     |    Blue
```

How do I only return the IDs that have one unique color?  i.e

```
ID_no |    Color
---------------- 
1     |    Blue 
1     |    Blue 
3     |    Red
```

I tried

```
select ID_no, color from table 
having count(unique(color)) = 1 
GROUP BY ID_no
```

But that doesn't seem to work, can someone help me out with the SQL syntax to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group by` and `having`:

```
select id_no
from t
group by id_no
having min(color) = max(color);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

```
SELECT ID, color FROM <tablename> GROUP BY ID HAVING MIN(color) = 
MAX(color);
```